Is it possible to use bash aliases in Apache Ant build.xml script?
I use Apache Ant for automate build program from sources. build.xml have exec task with command lazbuild which on my machine is not registered in path and needs to be called with some additional arguments. So I make alias in ~/.bashrc with command:
alias lazbuild="/home/artem/fpcupdeluxe/lazarus/lazbuild --pcp='/home/artem/fpcupdeluxe/config_lazarus' --lazarusdir='/home/artem/fpcupdeluxe/lazarus'"

It works fine when I manually type lazbuild in terminal, but when Ant start building it fails with error:

/home/artem/Projects/Lazarus/AutoScreenshot/build.xml:87: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "lazbuild" (in directory "/home/artem/Projects/Lazarus/AutoScreenshot"): error=2, No file or directory.

I tried to create alias also in ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile and new file aliases.sh in /etc/profile.d/ directory, but without success.
Any ideas how to do this?
Thanks.

Aliases are generally intended only for interactive use. You shouldn't expect to use them in scripts or other tools that execute shell commands.

Save yourself the trouble by turning your alias into a shell script. Create a ~/bin/lazbuild containing
#!/bin/sh
/home/artem/fpcupdeluxe/lazarus/lazbuild --pcp='/home/artem/fpcupdeluxe/config_lazarus' --lazarusdir='/home/artem/fpcupdeluxe/lazarus' "$@"

run chmod +x ~/bin/lazbuild, and add PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" in your .bashrc if you don't already have it. lazbuild will now work as a bona fide command in all contexts.

If you really want to use the bash alias, you have to invoke bash, enable alias expansion, source your definition, and invoke your command in a separate parsing unit. This is a very bad practice:
<exec executable="bash">
  <arg value="-c" />
  <arg value="shopt -s expand_aliases; source ~/.bashrc; eval lazbuild" />
</exec>


First solution works fine and completely suits me. Thanks!
